# cakephp 3.0 installation error after composer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

composer successfully 
as by command

```
Cake$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist -s dev cakephp/app Cake
```

when i used commend to start the server by command

```
bin/cake server
```

i got the following error

> PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/Cake/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cake/config/bootstrap.php on line 23 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Cake/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Cake/config/bootstrap.php on line 23

either i need to give 777 permission or other plz help me

Comment: does the autoload.php file exist?

Answer (score 0):

I have run also with the same issues `autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` but I solve it by just downloading the whole code from https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/download/3.0.1/cakephp-3-0-1.zip

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where did you put the whole code of cakephp 3 to your project directory?

Comment: I am using wamp so I put it in wamp\www\some_folder\